# Changing only release bearing and/or clutch fork

Tags: clutch, golf

I own a VW Golf Mk5 1.9 TDI year 2005.

I most probably have an issue with the release bearing and/or clutch fork and either the release bearing or the release bearing and clutch fork would need to be replaced.

There is more information about the possible problem that I'm encountering in [this question.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/53870/strange-ticking-noise-on-golf-mk5-1-9-tdi)

I want to know can I just replace only one or both of these parts (depending which one is causing the issue) without having to change anything else with the clutch or the car in general, or do I need to replace some other parts as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get away with replacing only certain things. But if you don't want to have to remove the transmission again in the near future, it is best to replace what you can while in there.

My opinion is if you have gone to the trouble to take the transmission out, might as well replace worn parts now. Some things may still be in serviceable condition. Others may not. That is why it is best to inspect components now and replace anything that is close to worn out.